# Facebook wrapping text

Tags: javascript, css, word-wrap

Please how to move word to next line if it's alone in this line? 
**(Facebook does this when adding ads)**

I use

```
word-break: break-word;
```

But it gives some lines with one word!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Could you show an example?

Comment: @Sanshiro please provide some code/example/fiddle/screen shot other wise how we can imagine that whats in you mind.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `word-break: break-word` is nonstandard and browser-specific. It is poorly documented but probably intended to do the same as `word-break: break-all` as per [CSS 3 Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/). This means allowing line breaks at any point, even inside a word, just breaking anywhere (without inserting a hyphen). This may be acceptable in some contexts, but surely not for normal English text, for example.

As a completely unrelated question, to prevent a word from being displayed alone in a line, you need to bind it together with an adjacent word. The simplest way is to use a no-break space instead of a normal space, e.g. replacing `<p>... foo bar.</p>` by `<p>... foo&nbsp; bar.</p>` To do the same in CSS, you need extra markup: `<p>... <span style="white-space: nowrap">foo bar.</span></p>`

Comment: Yup — at the risk of self-promotion, for links to documentation of `word-break` (and `-ms-word-break`), see http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/word-break — `word-break: break-word;` doesn’t seem to be officially documented.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for replay...plz tell me what am doing wrong?here is my code  <a style='text-decoration:none' href='{$ad_link}' target='_blank'><div id='ad_text_placeholder' class="ad_text pre"><span style="white-space: nowrap">{$ad_text}</span></div></a>

Comment: @Sanshiro, not enough context is given (what does `{$ad_text}` get expanded to?, but it seems that you are trying to create a link where no line breaks are allowed. Is this what you want, and how does it fail?

Comment: Hi,{$ad_text} is content from text area, User add it when submit ads. And it's still showing one word on some lines and even it breaks the word sometimes to half!!!!! please what to do?